# How to Backup Local SQL Database on a Cloud Service from a Flutter App

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-isar

I am writing a flutter app that stores data in a local SQL database ([Isar](https://isar.dev/de/)). I want to regularly backup this data on a Cloud Service and occasionally restore it in case a user has a new Phone. I am no expert in SQL or server maintenance and I am looking for an easy way to backup my data on a Cloud. Any experiences with this sort of setup or suggestions where to look are welcome!

I have thought of moving the project entirely to a cloud backend, but my setup does not play well with the popular services like firestore (many writes few reads) and I like keeping things mostly local.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the official guideline provided on the repository itself for backup.

It mentions using the following call:

```
isar.copyToFile()
```

Which you can use to upload to the cloud provider. For more information, you can refer to the link below:

https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/579

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33129842)

Comment: @slideshowp2 sure, I have added the main call for the function to perform. Thank you for the input.